Limit of $\frac{f(x)}x$ implies existence of limit of $\frac{f(x)}{|x|}$ with $x\to0$
I am trying to prove wether:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}\implies \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{|x|}$$
Or:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{|x|}\implies \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$
My idea was to rewrite $f(x) = k(x)x$ and then try to prove that the limit would still exist for $\frac{f(x)}{|x|}$. But, as you guys can already tell, the limit of $\frac{x}{|x|}$ would diverge, and now I'm out of ideas. Could anyone help?

If $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x=L\ne0$ then $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=L\ne-L=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}$ hence $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}$ does not exist.
Likewise, if $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=L\ne0$, then $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)}x=L\ne-L=\lim_{x\to0-}\frac{f(x)}x$ hence $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x$ does not exist.
Finally, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x=0$ iff $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=0$.

As you already mentioned, if $f(x) = x$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{x} = 1$, but $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{|x|}$ diverges.
Your best bet is taking one-sided limits, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x)}{-x}$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x}$, and only if they are both some common result $C$, then you can safely conclude that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{|x|} = C$. Oherwise, the limit doesn't exist.

In your second paragraph, using $f(x)=x$, you get some issues with your conclusion.

This answer is false.

oh I made a typo in the limits, thanks!
